# Address Sanitizer error in a Leetcode problem: 'Preorder Tree Traversal'

Tags: preorder

I am trying to implement the Morris Traversal of a Binary Tree in C++ for the "Binary Tree Preorder Traversal" problem on Leetcode. My code is failing on the test case: [3, 2, 1], where 3 is the root node, 1 is the left child, and 2 is the right child. I find that when I uncomment the two commented lines in the preorderTraversal method, the code works fine. As far as I can tell, the two commented lines are unnecessary for the solution, so I am not sure why they are causing an error.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */

vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<int> vals;
    while (root != nullptr) {
        if (root->left == nullptr) {
            vals.push_back(root->val);
            root = root->right;
        } else {
            TreeNode* last = root->left;
            while (last->right != nullptr) last = last->right;
            last->right = root->right;
            //TreeNode* temp = root; NOT INCLUDING THIS CAUSES ERROR
            vals.push_back(root->val);
            root = root->left;       
            //temp->left = NULL;     NOT INCLUDING THIS CAUSES ERROR
        }
    }
    
    return vals;
}
```

This is the error that was thrown:

```
Runtime Error Message:
=================================================================
==24==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x6030000003d8 at pc 0x00000038f4f5 bp 0x7ffd36eee010 sp 0x7ffd36eee008
READ of size 8 at 0x6030000003d8 thread T0
    #4 0x7f4383a9e082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
0x6030000003d8 is located 8 bytes inside of 24-byte region [0x6030000003d0,0x6030000003e8)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #5 0x7f4383a9e082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #4 0x7f4383a9e082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff8020: fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa
  0x0c067fff8030: fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd
  0x0c067fff8040: fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8050: fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa
  0x0c067fff8060: fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa 00 00
=>0x0c067fff8070: 00 fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd[fd]fd fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8090: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff80a0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff80b0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff80c0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==24==ABORTING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error does not occur in your code, but in the LeetCode testing code that calls your function. We can reproduce it with this tree:

```
              ┌─────┐
              │  1  │
              └┬───┬┘
            ┌─◄┘   └►─┐
         ┌──┴──┐   ┌──┴──┐
         │  2  │   │  3  │
         └┬────┘   └─────┘
       ┌─◄┘
    ┌──┴──┐
    │  4  │
    └─────┘
```

When your function returns, it leaves the tree in this state:

```
                 ┌─────┐
                 │  1  │
                 └┬───┬┘
               ┌─◄┘   └►─┐
            ┌──┴──┐   ┌──┴──┐
            │  2  │ ┌─┤  3  │
            └┬───┬┘ │ └─────┘
          ┌─◄┘   └►─┤
       ┌──┴──┐      │
       │  4  │      │
       └────┬┘      │
            └─────►─┘
```

After LeetCode has verified the returned vector it cleans up the memory allocated by the tree, and that is where the problem occurs. It will delete node 3 *a second time*, not expecting that this node has more than one parent. At the second `delete` operation, the exception occurs.

#### Avoiding the error

To avoid this from happening, you need to make sure to leave the tree in a state where it really is a *tree*: nodes should have at the most one parent.

Even the commented statements do not ensure that the tree is restored completely. In fact, it leaves the `left` pointer of the root node (and other nodes) set to `NULL`, which means that some subtrees are no longer reachable from the root node, and the LeetCode framework cannot completely clean up the memory used by the tree. So although the exception no longer occurs, it is not a *clean* solution.

#### Correct implementation

A Morris traversal will use a node's `right` pointer that is initially null to temporary store a pointer to the node's ancestor that is its inorder successor.

Here is an implementation that will have restored the tree correctly once all nodes have been visited:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<int> vals;
        while (root) {
            if (!root->left) {
                vals.push_back(root->val);
                root = root->right;
            } else {
                // Find the node's predecessor in its left subtree
                TreeNode* last = root->left;
                while (last->right && last->right != root) {
                    last = last->right;
                }
                if (last->right == root) { // Cycle! This is a temporary pointer.
                    last->right = nullptr; // Restore the memory that was temporarily used
                    root = root->right; // The left subtree has been visited, focus on right subtree
                } else {
                    last->right = root; // Temporarily use this memory to point to successor (ancestor)
                    vals.push_back(root->val);
                    root = root->left; // Visit left subtree -- we will eventually visit "last" there
                }
            }
        }
        return vals;
    }
};
```

Comment: I followed your explanation up until the point you said it will delete node 3 in your example twice. Firstly, doesn't node 3 have 3 parents (1, 2, 4) at the end? Secondly, how does the commented code ensure that each node has at most only 1 parent? As I understand it, 3 will have 1, 2, and 4 as parents, no?

Comment: Yes, node 3 has three parents. It is at the second attempt to delete that node that the exception occurs.

Comment: With the extra code uncommented node 3 still has 3 parents, but only one is reachable. After having processed node 1, its `left` pointer is set to `NULL` and this is never restored. By consequence the cleanup process of the LeetCode framework only frees the memory of node 1 and 3, as the other two nodes have become unreachable from the root.

Comment: So, even though with the uncommented code there is no more error, it is not good practice that the solution does not restore the tree to its original state, which is what a proper implementation of Morris traversal will do.

Comment: Added an implementation that correctly restores all pointers during the traversal, so that at the end the tree is just like it was at the start, and LeetCode will do its cleanup job as desired.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense now. I implemented your solution and it worked. Thank you so much.